# View and enable copy / paste of docx, xslx, pptx, pdf in web server

Tags: html, pdf, copy, docx, paste

I would like to be able to load document files into my webserver / application server (docx, xslx, pptx, pdf). I need to view the files in WYSYIG and be able to copy and paste.
I found several libraries however it's either not fully WYSIYG or not enable copy/paste.

Let me know if there is library like this, even if it requires some plugin.

Comment: Are you looking for a WYSIWYG written in JS that would work in the browser ?

Comment: Yes with ability to copy and paste text from the docx